# CTE delete not committed until following statements complete

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, sql-delete

The problem I'm having is that deleted data still appears later in the same query.  Naturally, in a completely separate query, the deleted data does not appear.

This isn't my use-case, but I think this it's the simplest way to show the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE company (id INT PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE employee (id INT PRIMARY KEY, company_id INT REFERENCES company(id), name TEXT);

INSERT INTO company VALUES (1, 'first company');
INSERT INTO company VALUES (2, 'second company');

INSERT INTO employee VALUES (1, 1, 'first employee');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES (2, 2, 'second employee');

-- this select can successfully query for the data which has just been deleted
WITH deleted_employee AS (DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = 1 RETURNING id)
SELECT id, name FROM employee JOIN deleted_employee USING (id);

-- this select shows it has been deleted
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

I've put it into a fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPjKrEBoR6sJqGamVdc8YE/0).

It seems the `DELETE` just isn't committed until the whole query has completed, which feels strange since the precedence requires that the `DELETE` occurs before the `SELECT`.

Is there any way to achieve this in a single query?

---

**Edit**

The answers have answered the direct problem.  The underlying problem is to delete an employee then delete its associated company, if there are no more employees associated with that company.

Here's the query I though would do the trick:

```
WITH affected_company AS (DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = 1 RETURNING company_id)
DELETE FROM company
USING affected_company
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM employee
  WHERE company_id = affected_company.company_id
);

SELECT * FROM company;
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

And an updated [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPjKrEBoR6sJqGamVdc8YE/1).

You can see the company isn't being deleted.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with that? If you only want to see the deleted rows then Johey's answer is probably what you are looking for. If not, then you will need to describe your actual requirement in more detail

Comment: I originally just wanted to understand what was going on, to avoid being spoon-fed a solution to my exact problem.  I've updated now that I understand better.

Comment: I understand that and your attempt to create a simply standalone example is laudable (rarely put that much effort into a question), but in this case more details were needed ;)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to delete in multiple tables with one single query, but if so I would be happy to learn how to do it. Maybe as a workaround you can do it with two queries, separated by a semicolon?

Comment: @johey I don't think there's a nice solution to this either.  I have posted a not-nice solution which works for the exact scenario described in my edit, just for educational purposes!  :)

Comment: @johey: yes it's possible ;)  See my updated answer

Comment: Wow, it seems one can do just about everything with SQL. 
select save the world!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected and documented.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), **so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables**. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that RETURNING data **is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

---

You *can* use chained CTEs to delete the company:

```
with deleted_emp as (
  delete from employee 
  where id = 1 
  returning company_id, id as employee_id
)
delete from company
where id in (select company_id from deleted_emp) 
  and not exists (select * 
                  from employee e
                     join deleted_emp af 
                       on af.company_id = e.company_id 
                      and e.id <> af.employee_id)
```

It's important to exclude the just deleted employee from the `not exists` sub-query as that will always be visible in the second delete statement and thus the not exists would never be true. So the sub-query essentially checks if there is an employee other than the deleted one assigned to the same company.

Online example: https://rextester.com/IVZ78695

Comment: Damn, how did I miss that.  The thing I still don't get is with this example `WITH t AS (UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05 RETURNING *) SELECT * FROM t;` it says _the outer `SELECT` would return the updated data_ which is not what I'm seeing.  How could the `DELETE` and `SELECT` run concurrently, if they have a dependency?

Comment: Oh I get it now!  Had to read that section a few times.  My question was solely asking about the behaviour which you've cleared up, so thanks both.  I've updated my question with the underlying problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!

Try this instead:

```
DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = 1 RETURNING *;
```

Edit: you don't need the CTE, just the DELETE statement with RETURNING * does the trick. :-)

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but this gives me that same result `WITH deleted_employee AS (DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = 1 RETURNING *)
SELECT id, employee.name FROM employee JOIN deleted_employee USING (id);` :(

Comment: Thanks!  This would indeed be a better solution to the simplified example I posted; however, it was more the behaviour which I didn't understand.  I've updated my question to explain the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs to be selecting from the CTE. 
This should give the same results as @johey answer.

```
WITH
  deleted_employee AS (
    DELETE FROM
      employee
     WHERE
       id = 1
     RETURNING
       *
  )
SELECT
  *
FROM
 deleted_employee
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the exact problem I described in the edit to my question:

```
WITH affected_company AS (DELETE FROM employee WHERE id = 1 RETURNING company_id)
DELETE FROM company WHERE id IN (
  SELECT company_id
  FROM employee
  JOIN affected_company USING(company_id)
  GROUP BY company_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
);

SELECT * FROM company;
SELECT * FROM employee;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPjKrEBoR6sJqGamVdc8YE/3).

It's essentially just a hack instructing the second `DELETE` only to act on the affected company if there was exactly one employee associated with that company at the original snapshot.

It's gross though and I won't be using it.